# How can I prove that this set is finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be a finite collection of open intervals such that $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k$. How can I prove that the set $A=\{x\in \mathbb{I} \cap [0,1] : x \notin \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k \}$ is finite?
($\mathbb{I}$ is the set of irrational numbers).

Comment: What's $\mathbb I$?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Irrationals?

Comment: Is this really true? Can $0$ be in any of the $I_{k}$ at all?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff No, $I_1 = (-1, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $I_2 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \infty)$ provides an example where the intervals don't cover the whole of $[0,1]$ and satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: @DevenWare Oh, derp. If the intervals have all rational end-points then the claim is true, however.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Agreed.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff In that example, $A=\{1/\sqrt2\}$, which is finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}I_{k}$ contains all rational points of $[0,1]$, then $[0,1]\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}I_{k}$ is a set consisting of the irrational endpoints of those $I_{k}$ that are not covered by any other $I_{m}$. Finiteness comes from the fact that there are only finitely many $I_{k}$, and thus only finitely many of their endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

The key idea is that there are only *finitely many* of these open intervals $I_k$.

Since they are intervals, we can write $I_k = (a_k, b_k)$ with $a_k < a_{k+1}$ and $b_k < b_{k+1}$ w.l.o.g. and also, w.l.o.g. each $b_k \in [0,1]$ for $k\ne n$ and $a_k \in [0,1]$ for $k\ne 1$

Now since the intervals cover all of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ we know we must have $b_k \ge a_{k+1}$ for each $k$. (what would happen if it was not?) But since there are only finitely many intervals this condition immediately implies that there can only be finitely many points in $A$ (can you see why?)

Notice that finitely many is crucial here, as we can fix $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, enumerate the rationals $q_1, q_2, \cdots$ and take intervals $I_k = (q_k - \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}, q_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$ and the total measure of the union is at most $\epsilon$, and hence there are tons of irrationals in $A$.